# How to rename XIB/NIB files in Xcode 3?

Tags: xcode, refactoring

How do I rename XIB/NIB files in Xcode? There is no "Refactor" option, and right clicking and choosing "Rename" does not work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration file `Info.plist` contains the name of the main XIB file. Changing the relevant property to match the new name should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you renaming the main window you can change the file reference in Info.plist.

Otherwise open up the main window XIB file in an editor, and change the variable between: `<string key="IBUINibName">`and`</string>`